# Trouble in retrieving contact information

Tags: android

I want to get the contact name from a number i had tried retrieving it through a query But i am not getting the result..It is returning the number itself.....I had  already saved that number to the contacts.

The code i tried is...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    String x = getContactNameFromNumber("+918281306132");
    System.out.println(x);
}
private String getContactNameFromNumber(String number) {
    // define the columns I want the query to return

    System.out.println("Entering into getContactNameFromNumber");
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME,
            Contacts.Phones.NUMBER };

    // encode the phone number and build the filter URI
    Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Contacts.Phones.CONTENT_FILTER_URL, Uri.encode(number));

    // query time
    Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(contactUri, projection, null,
            null, null);

    // if the query returns 1 or more results
    // return the first result
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        String name = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME));
        return name;
    }

    // return the original number if no match was found
    return number;
}
```

}

I also added a read phone state permission too. Somebody please help me to retrieve the contact name.

Comment: Your code seems ok. You can try to change `String name = c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(Contacts.Phones.DISPLAY_NAME));` to
`String name = c.getString(0);`
. Or you can try my [**snippet**](http://pastie.org/6035954). If it work, i'll add answer.

Comment: I had tried changing my code still its not working.

Comment: Do you see any abnormal in logcat ?

Comment: no its returning the number itself not the contact name

Comment: OK, i got the ans can u please post the ans so hat i can mark it as the right ans,Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try my snippet :

```
public static String findContactByNumber(String phoneNumber,
        ContentResolver cr) {

    Uri lookupUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(phoneNumber));

    String[] phoneNoProjections = { PhoneLookup._ID,
            PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME };

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(lookupUri, phoneNoProjections, null, null,
            null);

    try {

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            return cursor.getString(1); //1 is the display name index. 0 is id.

        }

    } finally {

        if (cursor != null)

            cursor.close();

    }

    return null;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the Following changes in your code

```
Uri contactUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(Phone.CONTENT_URI, Uri.encode(number));
```

and

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
    String name = c.getString(c
            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
    return name;
}
```

Try it out, hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                String name = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                System.out.println(name + "name");

                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    // Query phone here. Covered next

                }
            }
```

> This code is Working for me